# How to center a longtable in scrbook

Tags: longtable, scrbook

During a thesis project (in an scrbook) I try to center a longtable with data and graphics, which is always misaligned. On the search for a solution I stumbled upon a longtable MWE, that worked nicely. However, if I change the article class to scrbook the misalignment occurs. My new MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} &     \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} &     \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Do you have an idea or hint for me, why this is the case and how to get a center environment?

EDIT: Thanks for the comments. However, I could still reproduce the behaviour with this MWE and the table is not wider than the textwidth. But then the simple option [c] in the longtable solved my problem:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|c|c|c|}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `longtable` environments are automatically centered; thus, there's no need for the `\begin{center]` and `\end{center}` statements. If your `longtable` isn't centered, it's probably because it's wider than the textblock.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the layout of even-and odd-numbered pages in a `scrbook` document isn't identical. Nevertheless, the `longtable` environment will be centered *within the text block*.

Comment: The example as posted shows a centered table, with or without a `center` environment. I vote to close as unclear.